# Implementing sidebar menu in ios apps without making the viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Hi I am using SWRevealViewController or MMDrawerViewController to implement hamburger or sidebar menu in my app.
But the problem I am facing is that I want to add sidebar menu on viewcontroller3 but when I do so ,it shows no bar menu but if I make viewcontroller3 as my rootviewcontroller,it shows side bar menu flawlessly.
My question is how can I achieve sidebar menu in my ios app without making that viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller of the app.Kindly give your suggestions and help me to overcome this question.

Comment: why not implement your own. It's simple & easy.

Comment: I tried that too but implementing on using UIView causes the screen to stick to the controller and it becomes cumbersome to handle the Viewcontroller's rest controls or if I take an entirely new viewcontroller ,it shows the empty space behind rather than showing the viewcontroller's view.